# Configure an extension without modifying the project

Tags: scrapy

Can I somehow add an [extension](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#topics-extensions) to the scrapy project without altering the source?

The spiders are going to be provided by users of the system, as egg files. My requirement is I want to push the data crawled by spiders to a message bus.

However, I can't very well ask the users to include a `message-bus-push-extension.py` in the project. Instead, I want to listen for the `ext.item_scraped` signal, and push that data to my service.

I tried this in scrapy.cfg:

```
[settings]
default = tutorial.settings
[extensions]
tutorial.ext.SpiderOpenCloseLogging = 0
```

but no cigar.

Is extensions the right mechanism for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Extensions look like the way to go here, but `scrapy.cfg` files have no `[extensions]` section, at least the framework does not read them, only the `[settings]` one. `EXTENSIONS` is the setting to alter to enable extensions in projects. If you can change the `scrapy.cfg`, can you not have control on the settings? You say _"I can't very well ask the users to include..."_, why is that? can you explain a bit more what you have the hand on, and what users will customize?

Comment: @paultrmbrth I want users to upload scripts, like in scrapinghub, and store the results in s3 automatically. I suppose I can force them to put the s3 settings in, but I'd much rather do so with an extension that applies to _any_ spider. Oh, and I'm planning to run the spiders with scrapyd. Sorry, if this is confusing, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around this. It would also be nice to be notified when the spider is done -  via some sort of a message on a bus.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with how it works internally but you can check Scrapinghub's way of running crawl, with added custom extensions: https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapinghub-entrypoint-scrapy